# Sequential dependent markdown parameters

Tags: parameters, r-markdown

I would like to create a parameterized markdown document with two parameters where available options for the second input are dependent on the first. In my case I am dealing with a database of patients and visit dates, so the first input would be the patient ID, then code with generate a list of dates for that patient and the second input would be the index of the available. So something like:

```
---
title: "Dependent Inputs"
output: html_document
params: 
  MRN: "Medical Record in Database to Assess"
  D_idx: "The Date index from list for this subject"
---

# First get MRN:
params$MRN

# After user input MRN then filter and list possible dates
DB %>% filter(ID == MRN)  %>% select(Dates)

# Now enter date index for this MRN
params#D_idx

# Do the rest of the analysis using MRN and Date to get desired dataset ...
```

The interaction between the two doesn't seem possible. Tried using some shiny widgets as well but I am only interested in getting the user input to run the rest of the script, not rendering shiny outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of investigating the same.

After trying several shiny-like input structures, I went back to some well-established books on R markdown:

1. Xie, Allaire, and Grolemund's *R Markdown: The Definitive Guide*, and
2. Xie, Dervieux, and Riederer's *R Markdown Cookbook*

Indeed, `1` is a fairly basic text so I was not surprised that not metion anything of the likes (see [Chap. 15](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html)). However, `2` is much more advanced and still lacks any reference to interdependent parameters (see [Chap. 17](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html)).

And the reason is quite simple: the YAML header is not written directly in R, so many functionalities are just not available.

I guess the only solution would be a workaround. For instance, asking the user to choose whether to use the first or the last of the possible values despite not knowing what they are. Or, asking whether to check all or only the first of the possible combinations.